# Laravel 5.5 and Entrust

Tags: php, laravel, entrust

I am trying to apply roles and permission on Laravel 5.5 with Entrust.

I used this, as the documentation inside the: App\models\Role.php

```
<?php namespace App;

use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole;

class Role extends EntrustRole
{

    $owner = new Role();
    $owner->name         = 'owner';
    $owner->display_name = 'Project Owner'; // optional
    $owner->description  = 'User is the owner of a given project'; // optional
    $owner->save();

    $admin = new Role();
    $admin->name         = 'admin';
    $admin->display_name = 'User Administrator'; // optional
    $admin->description  = 'User is allowed to manage and edit other users'; // optional
    $admin->save();

    $manager = new Role();
    $manager->name         = 'manager';
    $manager->display_name = 'Company Manager'; // optional
    $manager->description  = 'User is a manager of a Department'; // optional
    $manager->save();
}

?>
```

However, when i am trying to assign role to a user I receiving this issue:

```
{
..
$owner = new Role();
$owner->name = 'owner';
...
}

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$owner' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)"
```

Can you advice me please?

Comment: where do you assign the role to the user??

Comment: Inside a Controller, with a post method - the user's email account 

$admin = \App\Role::find(2); 
     
 $user = User::where('email', '=', 'email@domain.tld')->first();

    // role attach alias
    $user->attachRole($admin); // parameter can be an Role object, array, or id

    // or eloquent's original technique
    $user->roles()->attach($admin->id); // id only

Comment: where's the owner variable in what you posted in the comment?

Comment: i changed admin to owner but still same issue. however there was a warning on my IDE about this error (T_variable) before i prevent in actions. Just follow this documentation https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust.

Comment: provide me with the line where this error is happening

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/9e530

Comment: now i see it lol, you need to put the code in a function man not plug it in the model class directly, you are new to oop from what i see :))

Comment: better use a seeder class

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a function/method ? ;)

```
<?php namespace App;

use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole;

class Role extends EntrustRole
{

public function setup() 
{
    $owner = new Role();
    $owner->name         = 'owner';
    $owner->display_name = 'Project Owner'; // optional
    $owner->description  = 'User is the owner of a given project'; // optional
    $owner->save();

    $admin = new Role();
    $admin->name         = 'admin';
    $admin->display_name = 'User Administrator'; // optional
    $admin->description  = 'User is allowed to manage and edit other users'; // optional
    $admin->save();

    $manager = new Role();
    $manager->name         = 'manager';
    $manager->display_name = 'Company Manager'; // optional
    $manager->description  = 'User is a manager of a Department'; // optional
    $manager->save();
}
}
```